# How to reintialize a string in Assembly (irvine masm) back to null?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I need to reinitialize a string back to being either empty or full of null values (?). How can i change my string back to being full of uninitialised null values?
for instance  if i have

```
s1 byte ?,?,?,?,?
```

so i have an empty string of 5 characters which are null

and then i do some operations that make the string like this:

```
s1 byte "hello",0
```

now what do i do if i wanna make it back to:

```
s1 byte ?,?,?,?,?
```

Answer (score 1):

Assemblers define the memory variables declared with `?` in **BSS** segment, which is **uninitialized**. Most operating systems in fact clear the memory allocated for BSS when the program is loaded (for security reasons), but programmers should not rely on this.
The BSS memory may contain garbage at the start of program and you should not assume that it contains NULL bytes.
When you *wanna make it back to* `s1 byte ?,?,?,?,?`, you don't have to do anything, it already contains garbage. Of course, you can store explicite NULL characters to `s1` at run time with `MOV` instructions, if it's essential for your program.

Comment: Thanks, also is there a way to resize a string?

Comment: *but programmers should not rely on this.* - Depends what OS you're writing for.  C compilers certainly do make asm that depends on a zeroed BSS.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/zeofqe shows GCC using `.zero 32` in the BSS for `int foo[8] = {0};` when compiling for GNU/Linux.

Comment: NULL isn't a character.  Perhaps you mean ASCII NUL (one L) as a fancy name for `0`, aka `'\0'` in C.  I usually write "0-terminated string" if I'm talking about an implicit-length C string.

Comment: When you want to reuse a memory variable for strings of different lengths, either allocate it in BSS **statically** with size corresponding to the longest of all strings, or allocate each string **dynamically** using service of the OS.

Comment: @PeterCordes `0x00` is not a **printable** character.  Arzaan is probably confused by Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: I was under the impression that the word NULL (all-caps) was definitely not correct technical terminology for a `0` byte.  Wikipedia claims that NULL can be valid usage, but does point out that it's not good, especially in contexts like this where you might also use some C terminology.  I'd say it's just wrong.  Plain "null" is also ok I guess, allowing consistent terminology with null-terminated linked lists.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string never uses NULL, only ever Null or null.  (I would have used `0` more of the time, not "null".  "null" makes it sound mysterious.)